# How to disable Material Theme wizard at IntelliJ Idea start

Tags: intellij-idea, material-design

I am using Material Theme on my Mac Intellij Idea 2018, now every time I start the IDE it will show the Welcome to Material Theme Wizard to help me set up the theme step by step.

I'd like to disable it when the IDE starts, How could I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Glad I wasn't the only one. Twas annoying the ... I didn't find it pleasant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Delete this plugin from Intellij Idea.
2. Download from here
   (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8006-material-theme-ui) 2.8.3
   version.
3. Install manually from Intellij Idea (Settings->Plugins->Install
   Plugin from disk) the archive (Material_Theme-2.8.3.zip)
4. If there will be any issues with colors, just delete from (in my
   case it is: C:\Users\grigo.IntelliJIdea2018.2\config\options) two
   files: material_theme.xml and material_custom_theme.xml.

Comment: Version 2.10.0 seems to have fixed the problem, so probably better to upgrade rather than downgrade now.

Comment: Yes, the newer version I used v2.9.4.2 has fixed the issue, thanks.